# Change color of part of image under mouse cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have an image in grayscale and I want to change some area of the image to color under the mouse cursor.

It's similar to flashlight in the dark (http://www.mantlelabs.com/flashlight/), but I want to change part of black/white image to colored image.

My only idea is to have colored image above the grayscaled and changing the opacity of colored image in the area under cursor with some canvas...

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is for answering specific technical questions regarding issues you have with your code. It is not a code writing service. Please provide your existing code and a specific question explaining why it isn't working

Comment: Using canvas is a good way of doing it. A css-only way would be to use filters (bad browser support). I think the best thing would to create a black and white version of your image on the server and send both to the browser. There you can use a simple js script to hide/show some parts

Comment: @freefaller Thank you for your comment. I was trying to find some solution by myself, but I was not able to get some clever idea and I thought there will be some easy solution. I just needed a direction how to do it... But next time I will try to write something by myself...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>With canvas is quite fun,</sub>
**but if you need something really simple:**

[image: Mousemove over image change image]

```js
$('.model').mousemove(function(e){
  
  var offs = $(this).offset(),
      p    = {x:offs.left, y:offs.top},
      mPos = {x:e.pageX, y:e.pageY},
      x    = mPos.x - p.x - 50,
      y    = mPos.y - p.y - 50;
      
  $('.gray', this).css({left:x, top:y, backgroundPosition: -x+'px '+-y+'px'});
    
});
```

```css
.model{
  position:relative;
  margin:0 auto;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/Tv0O1te.jpg');
  width:236px;
  height:322px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.gray{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/ozg5hsQ.jpg');
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<p style="height:1000px;"></p>

<div class="model">
  <div class="gray"></div>
</div>
  
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Here's another interesting example

```js
$('.model').on('mousemove', function(e){
  
  var x = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
  $('.gray', this).css({width: x});
    
});
```

```css
.model{
  position:relative;
  margin:0 auto;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/ozg5hsQ.jpg');
  width:236px;
  height:322px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.gray{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:0;
  height:100%;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/Tv0O1te.jpg');
  border-right:1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="model">
  <div class="gray"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

[image]

Comment: This is almost perfect! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I would use map and unfortunately you have to cut you image to few pngs... Or you can use mask  clipping. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/

Answer (score 0):

There is two way to make this:

First, manipulatin the data with canvas.getImageData().data (returning a pixel array, then you have to manipulate pixels in the range and finaly use putImageData) but it'll be very slow, sure !

Other way is to have image in grayscale, and colored image like you said, the trick is to use global-composite-operation
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_globalcompositeoperation.asp

Steps:

- Make a buffer with your colored image totaly drawed inside, make a 2nd buffer empty.
- You have your canvas, and 2 buffer.
- Drawing the grayscale image directly on canvas
- drawing your buffer1 in buffer2
- set composite operation to destination-atop
- drawing your shape at the given position (mouse), circle ? Or a shape saved in an other buffer
- set back composite operation to source-over

This will made the trick.
If you want more complex effects, just have to made your layer effect on a buffer and try some coposite operation :)

PS: of course we can do simple things with DOM, depends on what FX you want

Answer (score 0):

You can display the greyscale image by default and make use of .mouseover() event in jquery to hide the greyscale image and display the color image.
its quite simple if you use javascript or jquery. like below

```
$( "#greyScaleImg" ).mouseover(function() {
$( "#ColorImg" ).css("display","");;
});

$( "#ColorImg" ).mouseout(function() {
$( "#greyScaleImg" ).css("display","");;
});
```